# Service Aggregator Pattern would work in this situation?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices, software-design

A health related web app that has its own local database to save/retrieve patient's and their appointments information.
On other end hospital has its own in-house desktop application to create patient's and their appointments.

In web-app if I need to keep the information from both end. local and hospital's in-house.

One microservice is to retrieve information from hospitals.
and other microservices ( patients, appointments, doctors ) for web-app.

How to aggregate or keep local database be updated with the hospital's data?
Every time when user see the appointment calendar it should show both the appointments.

Any solution?